# Places to Share a Graphics Library for RISC-V

Tags: assembly, graphics, terminal, ascii, riscv

I have developed an open-source (MIT license) terminal-based graphics library in RISC-V and I am looking for places to get the word out about the project (such as mailing lists or forums).

So far I was planning on posting to the RISC-V Academic Community mailing list because I hope it can be used as a tool in teaching RISC-V assembly. Mainly I'm looking for some communities who may find this project useful?

https://github.com/cmput229/GLIR is the repo and https://cmput229.github.io/GLIR/ is the documentation to give people an idea of what this library is.

Comment: This isn't technically a programming question so it's off topic according to Stack Overflow rules.  But IMO we should consider letting this one slide.  (Although the question would be more useful if it linked to the project so this question itself can be useful to people who search for RISC-V text graphics.)

Comment: @PeterCordes This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow so i did try to be conscious of the rules. I didn't want to link directly to the project because I worried about people thinking I was just trying to use this post to promote the library and thus end up with it being taken down. If it actually would be allowed I can link to the repository.

Comment: Linking to your own stuff is fine if it's actually relevant.  Especially if it's free/open-source, and you have a link that isn't generating any ad revenue for you (e.g. a project on github or something, so people can have a look without visiting your own site.  Otherwise yeah it could look slightly spammy.  But I wouldn't flag spam when you're linking to your own project *for a valid reason*.  As long as the question can stand on its own even if the link does die, it's not a bad thing to have a link to something you're talking about).

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay thank you for this feedback. I will edit the post with a link to the project. I suppose this has the benefit of giving people an idea of communities that would be good to target too.